# how to search a string in multiple files in unix

Tags: linux, unix

I want to search a string in the directory (sub directories too) **/www/mydirectory**, the string is **parcel**. I have tried with the command **grep -r "parcel".** i got this from stackoverflow. But if i give this command, server is hanging up and displays nothing. Please help me in getting this.

Comment: grep -r parcel <DIR>. For example grep -r parcel .

Comment: The server "hangs up" because without the second argument (path to directory to search in) `grep` searches in stdin and waits for input from keyboard. Just do `Ctrl-D` to finish stdin input.

Answer (score 7):

Use this command

```
grep -nr "PARCEL" /var --color*
```

`-n` for printing line number within the file

`-r` searches recursively in sub-dirs as well

`/var` is the top-level path from which the search is done recursively in all the sub-dirs & files

`--color` highlights the grep'ed string in the output

Comment: I also use `-I` to ignore large binary files, `-H` to print file names  and `-n` to print line numbers (it's for GNU grep): `grep -RIHn <what> <dir>`

Comment: On macOS the above command *does not work* and errors with `no matches found: --color`. So for anyone looking for a **macOS unix compatible command**, use: `grep -nr --color=auto "parcel" /var`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you see that server is hanging up because there are a lot of files and it need time to search required word or can't find it because required string doesn't exist

```
grep -r "parcel" /directory
```

is correct command to search string under given directory.